# Is there a replacement header function? in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create a PHP page that redirects to URLs
When a user enters a PHP page, the page automatically redirects it to another page
For example, if the user goes to http://mysite/test.php?uid=044A7232214B80
The code will look for the uid that is in the domain in the phpMyAdmin tables and if there is a match the code directs the user to a URL that is also stored in the phpMyAdmin tables. I tried to use the header function problem that it only works with Relative URL (It searches the domain in relation to the current page) and I want it to work with domain addresses that directs the user to an external site

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$dBUsername = "username";
$dBPassword = "password";
$dBName = "mysite";


$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $dBName);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}

//define variables
$uid = $_GET['uid']; //"044A7232214B80";
$sql = "SELECT URL FROM redirection_table WHERE UID = '$uid'";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

//prepare statements
if (!$result = mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
    exit();
}
else {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if ($row){
        $URL = $row['URL'];
        if ($row['URL'] === null)
        {
          echo "Error:404";
        }
        else {
           header("Location; '$URL'");
        }
    }

    exit();
}
```

phpMyAdmin tables:
[image]

Comment: You use `;` instead of ':' in `header` function, correct format of `header` usage for redirect, `header('Location: https://googl.com');`

Comment: Also, the URL should not be quoted.

Comment: There's no such thing as "phpMyAdmin" tables. They're just MySQL tables. And phpMyAdmin is just an ide